# imported date == server UTC date: Proper handling of timezone/conversion?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, timezone

This has to do with TimeZoneInfo (i think) and matching up server events to end-user events.

When event occurs, it is recorded on my server as UTC.

My application users are required to choose their timezone. At some point, they need to upload their own event data.  I take their event data and match it with my server's data (by date, ignoring time), and reconcile...etc...

Ok, so the records aren't matching up because the database recorded them as UTC and the user has them as their own timezone....What is the proper way to do this?

At first I was thinking "easy, just convert the imported dates to UTC and perform the matching"....but now I am thinking I need to somehow make the application know what timezone the imported data is from *before* I convert to UTC.

If this is correct, what are the correct methods/classes to use to accomplish?

Should I be using the DateTimeOffset structure?

Thanks, kindly let me know if this doesn't make sense and I will amend accordingly.

Comment: Depends on the number of users. If you know it's a small set have them upload to you via UTC. If it is a large number of users that would make this task impossible then have them tell you/append to you somewhere the timezone and convert.

Comment: We can assume that I know their timezone as they are required to declare it in the account settings.  What I am trying to decide is the convert part.  All I care about is the date, not the time.  So do I just get the imported date, specifykind? or offset?, and convert to utc prior to the matching?

Comment: You already have your answer then. You must use time for conversions. If you care at all about data integrity. Process: 1. You get data 2.Run through conversion routine to convert to UTC. 3. commit to db. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ah nice, thanks for the link.  That method is exactly what I was missing.  heh...staring at this stuff for too long today I guess :)  thanks for your responses

Comment: Put it in answer for you...